# substring a string with conditions

Tags: regex, postgresql

i have a column that is containing values as below from a  tableXX

| file_name |
| --- |
| my_String1_20220103_144415.csv |
| my_String2_20220106_155730.csv |
| my_String3_20220108_153930.csv |
| my_String4_20220103_144470.csv |
| my_String5_20220103_144415.csv |

**My question is how to retrieve a string after the last two '_' succeeded by a point '.'**

to have an  output  as such

| file_name |
| --- |
| my_String1.csv |
| my_String2.csv |
| my_String3.csv |
| my_String4.csv |
| my_String5.csv |

I tried this query :

```
select substring(file_name from '(.*)_') as file_name  from tableXX
```

Comment: Can you try using REGEXP_REPLACE function and replace the substring matched by regex [`(?:_[^_\r\n]+){2}\.`](https://regex101.com/r/dtlg2Y/1) with a `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(file_name, '^([^_]*_[^_]*).*(\.[^.]*)$', '\1\2') as file_name  from tableXX
```

The `^([^_]*_[^_]*).*(\.[^.]*)$` regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `([^_]*_[^_]*)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this group value in the replacement pattern): any zero or more chars other than `_`, a `_` and again zero or more non-`_`s
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `(\.[^.]*)` - Group 2 (`\2` refers to this group value in the replacement pattern): a `.` char and then zero or more chars other than `.` char
- `$` - end of string

Here is a test:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tableXX
    (file_name character varying)
;

INSERT INTO tableXX
    (file_name)
VALUES
    ('my_String1_20220103_144415.csv'),
    ('my_String2_20220106_155730.csv'),
    ('my_String3_20220108_153930.csv'),
    ('my_String4_20220103_144470.csv'),
    ('my_String5_20220103_144415.csv')
;

select REGEXP_REPLACE(file_name, '^([^_]*_[^_]*).*(\.[^.]*)$', '\1\2') as file_name  from tableXX
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The part of the strings you want to replace apparently is a datetime. You don't need a RegEx which may be slow.

Using basic string functions (2 solutions):

```sql
SELECT
    OVERLAY(file_name placing '' from (LENGTH(file_name) - 19) for 17)
    , REVERSE(OVERLAY(REVERSE(file_name) PLACING '' FROM 4 FOR 16))
FROM tableXX;
```

> `OVERLAY` does not accept negative integers, this is why I used `LENGTH` too.

But given that you want to replace this datetime value with its specific format, if you still want to do it using a **RegEx** I'd suggest this:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(file_name, '_[\d_]+.', '.')
FROM tableXX;
```

> Replace the part beginning with an underscore, followed by integers or underscore and ending with a dot, by a single dot.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an option without a regex:

```
select concat(split_part(file_name, '_', 1), 
              '_', 
              split_part(file_name, '_', 2), 
              '.', 
              split_part(file_name, '.', 2))
from the_table
```

Not sure which one would be faster. Regular expressions are typically quite slow, but repeated calls with `split_part()` might not be fast either.